# cant find an element with selenium by a specific text the element contains, when i want to search for it by the specific text + a variable

Tags: selenium, variables, text, element, contains

I wanted to find an element by a specific text it contains. That worked well, but here is the problem.
There are multiple elements, all with a specific text that Contains "EU" and a Number...

For example: "EU 40" or "EU 30". Now I want to replace the Number by an variable, so that I can decide what number the specific text should contain.
Just let me show you my code:

```
real_size_btn = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='EU 40']")
real_size_btn.click()
```

This code is working, but what does not work is this code:

```
size = input("size:")
real_size_btn = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='EU "+size+"']")
real_size_btn.click()
```

Every time I run the second code it says: `"no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[text()='EU 41']"}"`

Hopefully somebody can solve this Problem, I would appreciate it a lot.

A little edit:
This is the main element:
EU 40

Above the main element is this element:

```
<input aria-describedby="pdp-buytools-low-inventory-messaging" id="skuAndSize__26126342" name="skuAndSize" type="radio" class="visually-hidden" value="26126342:7">
```

And under the main element are pretty much the same elements, but a little bit different because the other elements are other shoe sizes.
For example this is an element of an other shoe size:

```
<label for="skuAndSize__26126330" tabindex="-1" class="css-xf3ahq">EU 39</label>
```

above this element is this:

```
<input aria-describedby="pdp-buytools-low-inventory-messaging" id="skuAndSize__26126330" name="skuAndSize" type="radio" class="visually-hidden" value="26126330:6.5">
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: can you add some example HTML where it would show those EU sizes in the text? also, a little more of your code right before where you do `real_size_btn.click()` at the top

Comment: im really new to this whole topic, so i dont know if im answering you right, but I think this is the HTML:  <label for="skuAndSize__26126342" tabindex="-1" class="css-xf3ahq">EU 40</label> ... i know i just can find the element by for="skuAndSize..." , but the Number that comes after the "skuAndSize__" is for every shoe and every shoesize different, so thats not an option. To the code,                           
real_size_btn = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='EU 40']")
real_size_btn.click()                      ...This is actually everything that is in my "click_size" functio

Comment: please add it to the original post instead of as a comment.  Also, add more than just that one line....get a good amount of HTML above/below that specific piece

Comment: oh alright, i will do that.

Comment: so you are saying if you hardcode it directly it works fine?  Like this? 
 `browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='EU 40']")`

Comment: maybe add the URL too if you can

Comment: It is very confusing you have formatted all code and your comments as code.  Makes it hard to read.  But anyway, I don't see any `button` element at all in your HTML displayed.  Why are you calling for that in your code?  It would be better if you just copied and pasted a chunk of the HTML, and not inserted your comments between them

Comment: oh thats true, im sorry. Im totaly new to stack overflow, so please forgive me if i do anything stupid. Anyways it is working and the URL is this:    
https://www.nike.com/de/t/air-max-sc-herrenschuh-qqWL2v/CW4555-103

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use f-strings?

```
some_number = "your number"
real_size_btn = browser.find_element_by_xpath(f"//button[text()='EU {some_number}']")
```

Furhermore,
You can put your numbers to a list like this:

```
your_list = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
```

and access them as `your_list[0]`, `your_list[1]` and so on.

Comment: Agreed that is a better way of passing in a variable to a string but that doesn't solve the OP's issue

Comment: I see the question was just updated. Let's check

Comment: This worked aswell, thank you! I think i just made a big mistake right in the beginning. Thank you to all that helped me!

Answer (score 1):

can you try this

```
real_size_btn = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(.,'EU "+size+"')])";
```

Comment: i tried something little bit else, becouse i think you dont need the ";" but the ")":                                                                                                         
real_size_btn = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(.,'EU " + size + "')]")      and this was what i was getting:                                                                                      no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[contains(.,'EU 41')]"}

Comment: can you pls add your HTML or the URL if possible

Comment: ohh im really sorry, it did worked. I did a really dumb mistake. Thank you!

Comment: what was the mistake

Comment: You may upvote the answer that worked for you and accept it as correct answer